# Reference request for a paper by chen

Tags: reference-request

Could someone please help me in downloading the paper 'On the distribution of almost primes in an interval' by Jingrun Chen (journal: scientia sinica)? I was not able to find it on internet?

Any hel would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That article can be found online here:

https://www.sciengine.com/Math%20A0/doi/10.1360/ya1975-18-5-611

Comment: Thanks a lot...